# Why would someone need a Spatial Light Modulator with a maximum phase shift $> 2\pi$

Tags: image-processing

I am working with [Spatial Light Modulators](http://holoeye.com/spatial-light-modulators/slm-pluto-phase-only/) for a project and I was wondering why does the producer think someone would need a maximum phase shift $>2 \pi$ since the device works as a monitor and every phase-element monitored on the device could be reduced between $[0,2\pi]$ using a modulo?

Marko

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That will be useful at least for pulse shaping, because then it is not just a single wavelength that you are dealing with, and as modulo $2\pi$ is actually implemented as modulo of displacement, it would work only for a single wavelength, creating jumps in the phase for nearby frequencies.